# Bug in using self-defined font?

Tags: fonts, math-mode

As long as I do not use \bf, my font works fine.  Starting with $$ within which I first use \bf, and every instance thereafter, instead of getting the font I defined I keep getting bold letters.  How do I fix this?

The problem might lie in the fact that I defined my own font.  AMSFonts User Guide mentions several font families which can be used to define new fonts.  Since it does not tell how to do so, I had to hack together a way to define my own font which I called `\Cal`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newfam\calfam
\font\calten=eusm10
\font\calseven=eusm7
\font\calfive=eusm5
\textfont\calfam=\calten
\scriptfont\calfam=\calseven
\scriptscriptfont\calfam=\calfive
\def\Cal{\fam=\calfam}

\begin{document}
${\Cal O}$ ${\Cal O}{\bf a}b{\Cal O}$ ${\Cal O}$
\end{document}
```

The first `\Cal O` shows up fine; the rest show up bold instead.  Note that the b does NOT show up bold: so the bold-ness has obviously ended with the a.  However, the O's keep showing up bold thereafter.  How can I get regular `\Cal O`'s throughout my document?

Thank you in advance.  Update:

I found the answer:
[Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc/517?s=1|0.2087)

```
{\bf foo}, for example, resets all font attributes which had been set earlier before it prints foo in bold face.
```

In other words, when I used bf, I guess it reset some variable that I had not defined when defining my font.  While it would be nice to know how to define my font to allow it to go back to normal, I guess I will have to use the longer \mathbf in the meanwhile.

Comment: `\bf` is deprecated in LaTeX. Using either `\textbf` or `\bm` from package `bm` (bold math) instead, it works as expected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: See original post for response to comments.  Thank you!

Comment: Also, since you are using LaTeX, not plain TeX, you could just add `\usepackage{eucal}` and use the standard `\mathcal` to avoid the "hack together" method altogether.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question – that's not how this platform works :) Either wait for @PaulGessler to post an answer or, if he does not, self-answer.

Comment: @PaulGessler Well, the point was, the standard mathcal O prints like a regular O with a little gap in the middle, not large enough to see in print. That was why I wanted my own O, with a noticeable curve, which is not what regular MathCal gives.  Edit: Thank you, your answer does both.

Comment: @SeanAllred So...  what should I do now?  Technically what I edited into the post is not the "answer", just a workaround...  Please do explain, because this is a convention I have trouble understanding on other StackExchange forums as well.

Comment: @Alex I'm logging off for the night, but I'm certain we'd be happy to explain everything in chat if you drop on in :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical “don't do it” code. The instructions `\newfam` and `\font` should never be used in LaTeX at the user's level. For instance, if you change the point size option of your document from the default `10pt` to `11pt`, you'll have to manually modify the font assignments.

You should rather rely on the font selection scheme, which is not really difficult. First, define a font family

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{eus}{\skewchar\font'60}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{eus}{m}{n}{%
     <-6>eusm5%
    <6-8>eusm7%
    <8->eusm10%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{eus}{b}{n}{%
     <-6>eusb5%
    <6-8>eusb7%
    <8->eusb10%
}{}
```

(the `U` encoding is predefined, and it applies no “transformation”). Then you can define a new math alphabet

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\matheucal}{U}{eus}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\matheucal}{bold}{U}{eus}{b}{n}
```

In the document you'll use the “correct” syntax

```
$\matheucal{O}$ $\matheucal{O}\mathbf{a}b\matheucal{O}$ $\matheucal{O}$
```

With the `\SetMathAlphabet` instruction, the math alphabet will respect the `\boldmath` declaration and, if `\usepackage{bm}` is given, the code

```
\bm{\matheucal{O}}
```

will produce a boldface calligraphic “O” also under normal math version.

More than that, you'll ensure that the calligraphic letters have the correct size also in contexts where `\large`, `\small`, `\footnotesize` and similar declarations are in force, which will not be the case with your `\font` based approach.

This said, the `eucal` package does exactly what's outlined above; if you declare

```
\usepackage{eucal}
```

then Euler calligraphic will be output when `\mathcal` is used; if you want to keep the original meaning of `\mathcal` for using Euler calligraphic along with the default calligraphic (but you shouldn't, because the shapes are not so different from one another), load the package by

```
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
```

that will make Euler calligraphic available with `\mathscr`.

Comment: Thank you very much-- your suggestion worked.  But what can I do if `\matheucal` is already defined by another package, and I wish to use the same macro name? My re-definition does seem to take precedence, but LaTeX keeps complaining about it each time I re-compile the file...

Comment: @Alex Without seeing code it's not possible to suggest workarounds. Please, open a new question with a minimal example.

Answer (score 5):

`\bf` is deprecated in LaTeX, you should use `\textbf` instead if it's meant to be upright, or `\bm` with `\usepackage{bm}` for bold math if it's meant to be bold italic math.

Since you are using LaTeX, there's already a solution for your problem in the package `eucal`. With this you can avoid the "hack together" method entirely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,eucal}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
${\mathcal O}$%
${\mathcal O}{\bm a}b{\mathcal O}$%
${\mathcal O}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you do a printscreen to get this image to display on the forum?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes, I used Snipping Tool and uploaded the image. More details at [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2136)

Comment: `\bm` is not a font switch, it expects an argument... Same for `\mathcal`.

Comment: @karlkoeller you're right, and `a` (a single token) _is_ the argument. The same is true for `\mathcal`.